# git2go's CheckoutHead() not updating the index

Tags: git, go, libgit2

I'm trying to initialize a repository over an existing directory, add a remote and force checkout the remote's master branch over the existing files. The cli commands for this would be:

```sh
git init .
git add remote origin 'https://domain/repo.git'
git fetch
git checkout -f origin/master
```

Everything works fine but the index doesn't appear to change after the checkout. The relevant code is:

```go
# (init repo, add the 'origin' remote and fetch it...)
repo.SetHead("refs/remotes/origin/master")
repo.CheckoutHead(&git.CheckoutOpts{Strategy: git.CheckoutForce})
```

When I do a `git status`, I see the same files appearing as deleted (D) in the index and also as untracked (yes, the same file appears as both), while the workdir does contain the correct files. Since this looks like the index wasn't written to disk from memory, or has some weird cache, I also tried `index.Write()` after the checkout but that didn't make any change.

If I run `git reset HEAD` in the repo, then `git status` returns a clean state, since the index gets updated to the current HEAD tree and it now reflects the workdir.

#### Update

I noticed this only happens when the files in the existing directory are the same as in the origin repo (file mode isn't important). In this case those files appear as deleted (D) and untracked (??).

It doesn't happen when the file exists but has a different content. In this case the file correctly appears as modified (M).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by reading the tree into the index and writing the index to disk before the checkout. The code looks something like this:

```
repo.SetHead("refs/remotes/origin/master")
# get the index and the HEAD tree...
index.ReadTree(headTree)
index.Write()
repo.CheckoutHead(&git.CheckoutOpts{Strategy: git.CheckoutForce})
```

This appears to have the same effect as running `git checkout -f origin/master`. But I don't know why the [`ReadTree()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_read_tree) is necessary, since [`CheckoutHead()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/checkout/git_checkout_head) **should** update the index *and* the working tree, [per the docs](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/checkout/git_checkout_head):

> **git_checkout_head**
>   Updates files in the index and the working tree to match the content of the commit pointed at by HEAD.

My best guess is that the checkout doesn't work correctly because the index points to an empty tree initially. However I'm not sure if it's a libgit2 bug or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't update `HEAD` before checking our or your working directory will be dirty and checkout will (likely) not be able to proceed.  Instead checkout *to* what you want, and *then* update `HEAD` if checkout succeeds:

Something like:

```
target, err := repo.LookupCommit(newHeadId)
repo.CheckoutTree(target, &git.CheckoutOpts{Strategy: git.CheckoutSafe})
_, err = repo.References.Create("refs/heads/master", commitId, true, "master")
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I noticed that this method works, but `git_checkout_head()` says it updates the index and the working tree, so I would expect it to work similar to `git checkout -f HEAD` (especially when using it with --force), why isn't this true? Also what if I have an already dirty worktree and I want to sync the worktree with the index, as I would do with `git checkout -f`? Seems to me that `git_checkout_head()` is pretty useless (with --force at least).

Comment: It does update the index and the working tree.  Your example (above) shows `git checkout -f <branch>` and then tries to equate that with `git_checkout_head`; they are not the same.  If you are seeing differences between `git_checkout_head` and `git checkout -f HEAD` (when following the same steps) then please elucidate that in a further question or an issue.

Comment: Alright. I am seeing differences between `git checkout -f HEAD` and `git_checkout_head()`, so I will create a reproductible test case and open an issue in libgit2 (but using git2go since it's easier for me). Thanks.

Comment: I also don't understand why the docs for `git_checkout_head` say that it updates the index and the working tree to match the commit pointed to by HEAD when it obviously doesn't.

Comment: @asandroq Absolutely it does.  The problem is that when you change `HEAD` _before_ a checkout, your working tree is now dirty.  You will see that if you change `HEAD` arbitrarily and then run `git status`.  If you then do a `git checkout HEAD`, it will try to checkout that data, but there's no guarantee that it can - because your worktree is dirty.  Do the checkout in your pristine state, then update `HEAD` if it was successful.  We've updated the documentation to explain this better.